# Conditional configurable horizontal space (like \mathop{})

Tags: math-mode, spacing

To typeset the integral/differential d it is common to define it as `\mathop{}\!d`. this is a neat trick that adds a thinspace if preceded by "regular stuff" like you'd expect in integrands, but doesn't if it's at a beginning, like right after + or (.

Now i want this same behaviour of conditional space, but with a different (slightly bigger), ideally configurable, size.

I tried with mathbin and mathrel, but they display different undesired behavior.

How can it be done?

Edit: MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\!} %\, works
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline
\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathbin{}\negmedspace} %\: doesn't
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline
\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathrel{}\negthickspace} %\; doesn't
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline
\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathbin{}} %\:\: works, too big
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It would help if you provided an MWE showing your attempts, and pointing out examples of bad (and good) behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps since I consider this a rather abstract question, but here you go.

Answer (score 1):

The amsmath command `\mspace` can be used more generally to achieve better control over horizontal space in a mathematical environment. Notice that the command is dependent on the mathematical font size. In contrast, the command `\hspace` will produce the same amount of space whatever mathematical font size.

Recall that one math unit (mu) is 1/18 of an em. For instance, in the first example (the reference) in the code-block sample below, the negative spaces `\!` is equal to 3 mu. Of course, the values inside the square brackets of both the commands `\mspace` and `\hspace` can be fine tuned at will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\!} %\ The Reference
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\hspace{-0.05em}} %\ 0.9 mu
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\hspace{-0.15em}} %\ 2.7 mu
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\hspace{-0.2em}} %\ 3.6 mu, slightly larger than the Reference
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\hspace{-0.3em}} %\ 5.4 mu
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline



\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\mspace{-3mu}} %\
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\mspace{-3.5mu}} %\ Slightly larger than the Reference
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline


\renewcommand*{\sp}{\mathop{}\mspace{-4mu}} %\
Test: $a \sp a(\sp a + \sp a$. \newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know how to just add space. the idea is to have it conditional, it needs to appear in some places an not in others. after the parenthesis and around the plus there needs to be regular spacing.